# find complete text in a one file and replace the string in another file

Tags: awk, sed, cat

I have data like this in Source_file.txt

```
5daee1ef55297ba2fac78933
```

And in Target_file.txt has

```
$$API_JOB_ID=5daed2a255297ba2fac78930
$$API_JOB_RES=succeeded
$$API_SERVER=awsabc1108
```

Now, I need to replace the `Source_file.txt` value in `Target_file.txt`.

Output should be like below

```
$$API_JOB_ID=5daee1ef55297ba2fac78933
$$API_JOB_RES=succeeded
$$API_SERVER=awsabc1108
```

Please note that **Source_file.txt** values are dynamically changing every time when other processes completed. Hence Target file has to be updated every time with correct `$$API_JOB_ID`

I would need the Unix command to resolve this.

Comment: What is the interval of updating Target_file.txt? Or what invokes the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is kind of *dirty*, but it should work:

```
sed 's/\$\$API_JOB_ID=.*$/\$\$API_JOB_ID='"$(cat Source_file.txt)"'/' Target_file.txt
```

If you want to directly edit your target file instead of printing the modified version to your terminal, use this instead:

```
sed -i 's/\$\$API_JOB_ID=.*$/\$\$API_JOB_ID='"$(cat Source_file.txt)"'/' Target_file.txt
```

---

It's *dirty*, mainly, because I'm making **TOO MANY** assumptions about the format of your files, and the command success, heavily depends on those assumptions; if we want to do this *right*, we need to know exactly what assumptions we can make, but your description was kinda vague. If you think that this can fail cause you can have other formats or more complex structure in your `Source_file.txt` and `Target_file.txt` files, we need to know about that.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Its perfectly working. Thanks very much for your time and really appreciate you.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful for you; could you please mark my answer as the one that solved your problem?

Comment: You perfectly made the correct assumptions and exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Million and appreciate your time on this.  Sorry to ask you this. How do we make it as its answered?.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work